# Printing binary tree by levels in java

Tags: java, printing, binary-tree, levels

I want to know the code to print a binary tree level by level, I mean, if I have this tree:

```
    5
   / \
  3   2
 /     \
4       6
```

I want to print it like: `5 3 2 4 6`.

I know I need to do the tree depth method and I already did it, but I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Use a queue to enqueue the child node and pop out the next node to print.

Comment: @nhahtdh I can't use any other data structure rather than the binary tree

Comment: @alfasin No, I don't know what is BFS, how can I use that in this method?

Comment: If you'll google it you'll find thousands of implementations, for example: http://www.divms.uiowa.edu/~sriram/21/fall05/ExamplePrograms/ReaderFiles/Chap13/bfs/bfs.java
you can read more about BFS here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Comment: @nhahtdh EDIT: it's for homework

Comment: @alfasin That may work but I cannot use queues. The only thing I know is that I have to do a "for" or "while" loop that starts in 0 and finish in tree depth.

Comment: @JohnnyDahdah: You can implement your own queue - the teacher should not prevent you from doing so.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Actually she did, she said "You cannot use any data structure rather than the binary tree you have"

Answer (score 3):

You can use the level traversal algorithm to print them.

The algorithm works as follows:

> queue := < root >
>
> while queue is not empty
>
> ```
>  v := queue.front
>
>  print v
>
>  foreach s : s is a son of v
>
>     queue.enqueue(s)
>
>  queue.dequeue
> ```

Comment: and by the way, `push` and `pop` are methods of `stuck`, not `queue`. For `queue` it's usually `enqueue and `dequeue`

Comment: @JohnnyDahdah why not? A queue is so easy to implement. There only need an array with two variables recording the head and the tail.

Comment: @KunHuang: I know but the teacher said "You cannot use any data structure rather than the binary tree you have"

Comment: @alfasin Thanks for your remind. I usually use C++, so I mix up the queue in STL and in common algorithm representation. But you also has a mistake: stack is spelt as stuck. :-)

Comment: @JohnnyDahdah eh, you can add a pointer field in every nodes of the binary tree to link the nodes as the output order.

Comment: @KunHuang I guess I got `stuck` with his question... :)))

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I figured it out:
1. extend the class Node and add a property called height (int)
2. Calculate the height of each node of the tree (easy recursive function  - no data-structure is needed)
3. use a for-loop, and run in-order traversal, for each height (level) and print the nodes of that level

Answer (score 0):

```
public void displayByLevel(){
    ArrayList<Node> ar = new ArrayList<>();
    ar.add(root);
    displayByLevelHelper(ar);
}
private void displayByLevelHelper(ArrayList<Node> ar){
    if(ar.isEmpty()){
        return;
    }
    ArrayList<Node> nextAr= new ArrayList<>();
    for(Node n:ar){
        System.out.print(n.data + " ");
        if(n.left!=null){
            nextAr.add(n.left);
        }
        if(n.right!=null){
            nextAr.add(n.right);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    displayByLevelHelper(nextAr);
}
```